# Azure ML Studio - Error when deploying real-time inference to endpoint

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I just started working with Machine Learning using Azure ML Studio.  I have been able to successfully train a model and create a real-time inference pipeline as well.  When I try to deploy the real-time inference pipeline to an endpoint, it keeps vascillating between Unhealthy and Failed.

When I look through the logs, there is only three logs that point to a possible problem:

> Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.ReusedStepRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:StepRun._from_reused_dto with exception (urllib3 1.26.9 (/azureml-envs/azureml_9a27d0b682f7325ef536eaeb801b2a62/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<=1.26.7,>=1.23'), {'azureml-core'}).

> Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.StepRun = azureml.pipeline.core.run:StepRun._from_dto with exception (urllib3 1.26.9 (/azureml-envs/azureml_9a27d0b682f7325ef536eaeb801b2a62/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<=1.26.7,>=1.23'), {'azureml-core'}).

> Failure while loading azureml_run_type_providers. Failed to load entrypoint azureml.scriptrun = azureml.core.script_run:ScriptRun._from_run_dto with exception (urllib3 1.26.9 (/azureml-envs/azureml_9a27d0b682f7325ef536eaeb801b2a62/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<=1.26.7,>=1.23')).

While this maybe something easy to fix if this was built in a Notebook, all of my components were built using Azure ML Studio, so I didn't acutally write any code to perform these steps, just using the Azure ML Studio UI.

Any help towards fixing this would be appreciated.